# setMargin method in Android

Tags: android

Take a look at the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static ArrayList<Color> colorList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("Info");
        data.add("Assessment");
        data.add("Billing");
        data.add("Release");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
        GroupAdapter groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this,data);
        setListAdapter(groupAdapter);
        getListView().setDividerHeight(10);
    }

    void init(){
        colorList = ColorList.get();
    }

}
```

I want to set the margin of the ListView in the ListActivity but there is no setMargin method in the ListActivity.getListView.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` for for changing margin of ListView :

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)
                                         getListView().getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: Opps! It crashed! Saying: Sorry! The application has stopped unexpectedly. System failed to repair the error. Please use other software. With no error logs recorded in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("Info");
    data.add("Assessment");
    data.add("Billing");
    data.add("Release");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    GroupAdapter groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this,data);
    setListAdapter(groupAdapter);
    getListView().setDividerHeight(10);

    //setting the margin
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) getListView().getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
}
```